# How to make select metabox in wordpress with update?

Tags: php, wordpress

I made a **metabox** in my post type:

```html
<p>
 <label for="movies_notifications_meta_caption"><?php _e( 'last', 'movies_notifications_caption' ); ?></label><br>
 <select name="movies_notifications_meta_caption" id="movies_notifications_meta_caption" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'movies_notifications_meta_caption',true ); ?>">
 <option value="360p" <?php selected( $selected, '360p' ); ?>>360p</option>
 <option value="480p" <?php selected( $selected, '480p' ); ?>>480p</option>
 </select>
 </p>
```

and here is my update code:

```
if( isset( $_POST['movies_notifications_meta_caption'] ) )
 update_post_meta( $post_id, 'movies_notifications_meta_caption', 
esc_attr( $_POST['movies_notifications_meta_caption'] ) );
```

It works very well and I can choose from the select menu and show it where I want. but there us a problem that when I select for example second choice and update the post, actually it works and in my page it will change. but in my **wordpress** dashboard and in my post type edit page, it's always on the first choice and if I forget to change it, and update the post, it will change in my website too. thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see definition code for $selected variable. If to add it, it should work without a problem:

```
 <?php 
 $selected=get_post_meta($post->ID,'movies_notifications_meta_caption',true ); 
 ?>
 <p>
 <label for="movies_notifications_meta_caption"><?php _e( 'last', 'movies_notifications_caption' ); ?></label><br>
 <select name="movies_notifications_meta_caption" id="movies_notifications_meta_caption">
 <option value="360p" <?php selected( $selected, '360p' ); ?>>360p</option>
 <option value="480p" <?php selected( $selected, '480p' ); ?>>480p</option>
 </select>
 </p>
```